# How to take count from DB by LINQ and where

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a problem. I want to make my application faster. My problem is:

```
_context.Products.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(part)).Take(20);
```

I don't want to take the whole collection, I want to take only part of it. I want to take elements, until I have enough elements that satisfy  my conditions, and I do not go through my entire collection to get my result. Can I get that with standard LINQ and EF Core methods?

Comment: Have you try it? I believe that `.Take(20)` part of LINQ will translate to `LIMIT 20` SQL statement.

Comment: Mostly yes. Until you invoke ToList or start interating on this collection all LINQ and EF methods are converted into SQL. Please read about IQueryable interface. For  example above code will be converted into SELECT TOP 20 * FROM Products WHERE <your_condition>

Comment: @Wokuo, then, context it`s like a builder for requests?

Comment: @vasily.sib, earlier i thought, it was like a execute methods in order. =\

Comment: @ВиталийЗаярний, no, its like building a query

Comment: @vasily.sib, yeah, i got it , when Wokuo wrote about "For example above code will be converted into SELECT TOP 20 * FROM Products WHERE <your_condition> "

Comment: more then that, if you using Visual Studio, you can see actual SQL requests in your output window.

Comment: @Виталий Заярний simplifying yes, it's some kind of query builder

Comment: @Wokuo, can you put your comment into answers fields? and i mark your answer like a correct answer, and i will close question.

Comment: @Виталий Заярний sure, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly yes. Until you invoke ToList method or start iterating on this collection all LINQ and EF methods are converted into SQL. It works little bit like a query builder, iteration is a trigger to execute query in this case. Please read about IQueryable interface.

For example above code will be converted into 'SELECT TOP 20 * FROM Products WHERE '

Answer (score 0):

Below my answer is based on assumption that you want to get data in chunks instead of taking whole collection at once to make your application run faster.

> "I don't want to take the whole collection, I want to take only part
>   of it."

You need to play with both the Skip and Take methods.

For example you can assume a static page size e.g. 20 in your case. 
And then while querying for the results you need to specify the page index against which you want to get data. To get how many pages are there against your query result, you can first take the count of the records and store it somewhere on clientside/in-memory/cache.

```
return _context.Products.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(part)).Count(); // to get the total number of records e.g. 74
```

Then to fetch the chunk of data you specify the page size and page index.

```
_context.Products.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(part)).Skip(PAGE_INDEX*PAGE_SIZE).Take(PAGE_SIZE);
```

PAGE_INDEX and PAGE_SIZE are input parameters for your function.